# Convert pointer address to original instance

Tags: pointers, rust

If I get an address of a pointer in Rust and convert it to a numeric type, for example like this:

```rust
let map: HashMap<i32, String> = HashMap::new();
let ptr = std::ptr::addr_of!(map); 
let ptri = ptr as i32;
```

Can I get back the original instance (`HashMap` in that case) from `ptri` variable?

Something like in C:

```c
HashMap *map = (HashMap*)(uintptr_t)ptri;
```

Comment: Rust's equivalent of `uintptr_t` is `usize`, so you probably want `let ptri = ptr as usize`,

Comment: Note that whether this is valid is yet undecided - can't find the relevant discussion right now, but key words are "pointer provenance".

Comment: @Cerberus It _is_ allowed, and always will be (exposed provenance and angelic non-determinism, although `as` casts may be deprecated in the (far) future but it'll always work with `expose_addr()`/`from_exposed_addr()`). The only discussion is about adding better ways (you're looking for the "strict provenance" effort).

Comment: Nitpick: `addr_of!()`? Just use `&map as *const _`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only if you are on a 32-bit machine. Otherwise, the cast of the pointer to an `i32` will truncate, and you won't be able to get the original address back. Switching to use an `isize` to handle pointer-sized integers instead, you can cast the pointer back to the `HashMap` type, dereference it, then borrow that instance of the hash map:

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let map: HashMap<i32, String> = HashMap::new();
    let ptr = std::ptr::addr_of!(map);
    let ptri = ptr as isize;

    println!("{:?}", map);
    println!("{:?}", ptr);
    println!("{:?}", ptri);
    println!("{:?}", unsafe {
        &*(ptri as *const HashMap<i32, String>)
    });
}
```

Comment: You don't want to use `read` or `read_unaligned` since you'll cause a double-free (unless you've appropriately prepared the original value to not free)

Comment: @kmdreko I didn't realize there was a way to deref raw pointers *without* the possibility of a double free. I thought that was one of the purposes of the `unsafe` block, is there a "safe-ish" way that is better?

Comment: You can convert a pointer directly to a reference (requires `unsafe`): `ptri as *const HashMap<i32, String> as &HashMap<i32, String>`

Comment: The compiler made me deref and borrow before the cast (`&*(ptri as *const HashMap<i32, String>) as &HashMap<i32, String>`), but that's neat. I can see how it gets a reference instead of owning a shallow copy (preventing the double-free), but `&*` looks really weird. I'd vote up you if you made that an answer.

Comment: The compiler suggested shorter versions for me, only `&*(ptri as *const HashMap<i32, String>)`. Thanks a lot, I would definitely vote up you both.

Comment: Neither `addr_of!()` nor `read_unaligned()` is needed here.